# How is Cloudant different from and related to CouchDB?

Tags: database, couchdb, cloudant

The only thing I understand so far is that Cloudant provides cloud support and uses CouchDB in the backend.

Comment: There was a big difference between Cloudant and CouchDb 1.6.1 but now with the new Release, Cloudant gave most of his code to CouchDB. It will be now possible to use the Mango Syntax(Based on Cloudant), Clustering, the new Fauxton UI, etc.

Answer (score 15):

**Cloudant vs CouchDB 1.6**

- Cloudant is horizontally scalable (with respect to data size), CouchDB isn't
- Cloudant offers full text search, CouchDB doesn't
- Cloudant has a different authentication system
- Cloudant has Cloudant query which allows you do declaratively set indices and query the DB. With CouchDB, you have to use views.

**Cloudant vs CouchDB 2.0**

- Cloudant offers full text search, CouchDB doesn't (though you can get it if you're willing to do a custom compilation)
- Cloudant has a different authentication system

Apart from these differences, there's the obvious one where with Cloudant you don't have to worry about provisioning and managing the servers, in exchange for a payment.

As to how Cloudant is related to CouchDB, CouchDB is obviously core to Cloudant's offerings. However, Cloudant has also contributed a lot of code to CouchDB resulting in some key features in 2.0 (horizontal scalability, query). Quite a few Cloudant employees are also on the CouchDB PMC.