# What is different between Cloudant db and couchdb

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, database, nosql

In my mind I have couple of questions listed below for these two db,

What are difference between these two db for the below term?
1. underlying architect
2. Performance wise
3. Query performance
4. How to deal with billion of data

Which one is better two use right now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is Cloudant different from and related to CouchDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972019/how-is-cloudant-different-from-and-related-to-couchdb)

Comment: @Kul I am looking for other things which is not asked in the above mentioned question.

Comment: The original version of the question made it sound similar to the linked question. I'm removing the duplicate flag I had raised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloudant is database-as-a-service owned and operated by IBM. It is actually Apache CouchDB but with some minor differences

- a different authentication API
- the option of GeoSpatial indexes
- built-in Lucene-based, free-text search indexes - this technology has been open-sourced but does not feature in the Apache CouchDB out of the box

CouchDB 2.0 effectively *is* the same codebase as Cloudant's service, so there is no difference in terms of scalability or performance - the only difference is the CouchDB requires that you have to install it yourself where-as Cloudant is provided as-a-service (at a cost).

Which you choose depends on the skill set you have in your organisation, your use-case and your budget. Some folks choose a combination of the two e.g. Cloudant as the primary data store with on-premises CouchDB as a backup.